# function called by constructors of derived classes not supposed to be pure virtual in base class

Tags: c++, constructor, pure-virtual

I have a base class and many derived classes.

The constructor of derived classes all need to call a function `reset()` with the same signature. As a result, I want to declare a pure virtual function `virtual void reset() = 0` in base class as an Interface.

However, the problem is :

It is not supposed to call a virtual function in Constructor.

But I want `reset()` to be an interface provided by the base class. So that all derived classes have to implement reset respectively.

What should I do?

Comment: You absolutely can call a virtual method implemented in a derived class in the derived class's constructor. It will call `Derived::reset()` but it won't call any overloads introduced by classes deriving from `Derived` if you are creating a more derived object. So calling virtual methods that should act as `final` is fine.

Comment: Why do all derived classes need to call that function? It has no default behaviour, so I can't see why the base class would care about whether a derived class called it or not.

Comment: Yes, the code can work. However, this practice is not recommended. I want a more elegant solution.@Quimby

Comment: Because this is old code needs refactoring. The derived classes call called that function.@molbdnilo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of forcing them to call a function (which you anyway cannot guarantee), make the base class constructor expect a parameter that includes the behavior you need to have.

That way, the base class is self-contained and has all the required information by the time its constructor runs.

---

For example, if you were thinking of something like this:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        reset();
    }

protected:
    virtual void reset() = 0;
    void setValue(int value);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void reset() override
    {
        setValue(20);
    }
};
```

you can do this instead:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    explicit Base(int value)
    {
        setValue(value);
    }

private: // can be private
    void setValue(int value);
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    : Base(20)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks like to be solution suggested in Effective C++ by Scot Meyers. But my reset is more complicated than setting a value. And, I don't want to change the constructors.

Comment: Could you elaborate what exactly `reset()` does and why it's impractical to adjust constructors? Please edit your initial post accordingly.

Comment: `reset` does some initialization work for different classes respectively. There are dozens of remaining derived classes initialized this way.

Answer (score 1):

You might create factory:

```
struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void reset() = 0;

    template <typename Der, typename ... Ts>
    static std::unique_ptr<Der> Make(Ts&&... args)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, Der>::value, "!");
        auto p = std::make_unique<Der>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        p->reset();
        return p;
    }
};

struct Derived
{
    void reset() override { /*..*/ }
};
```